# convert opus to wave in java script

Tags: javascript, webapi

I am trying to convert opus to wave in my code any suggestion how 
here is my code i use a recorder to record the microphone voice and then send it over socket

```
function hasUserMedia() {
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
   navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
   navigator.msGetUserMedia;
    return !!navigator.getUserMedia;
   }

   var yourVideo = document.querySelector('#yours'),
 theirVideo = document.querySelector('#theirs'),
 yourConnection, theirConnection;
 if (hasUserMedia()) {
  let socket = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.26.146:8000");
   console.log("test")
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true,video:false})
  .then(function(mediaStreamObj){
    let audio =  document.querySelector('#yours');
    var options = {
      audioBitsPerSecond : 8000,
      mimeType : 'audio/webm\;codecs=opus'
    }
    let mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStreamObj, options);
    console.log(MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported( "audio/webm\;codecs=opus"));

    mediaRecorder.start();
    setTimeout(() => {    mediaRecorder.requestData();; }, 2000);
    setTimeout(() => {     mediaRecorder.requestData();; }, 4000);
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(ev){

      socket.send(ev.data);
    }
  });

}
```